# AspNet Core Autofac disposing my DbContext even if its registered as SingleInstance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

In our application, we have an api which will store some data to a database. We are using `Entity Framework Core 3.1.1`. After this entity has been stored, a message is posted to `Azure Servicebus` and a consumer will read this message a store the message to another table in the same `DbContext`.

As far as I understand, a `LifetimeScope` is defined per request to the api. The `LifetimeScope` will start when the api request hits the `ApiController` and finishes when the endpoint is done processing the request.

The issue we are facing is related to the `DbContext` being disposed, so it cannot be used in the Consumer sinced its disposed.

From our code its pretty obvious why it fails. The `DbContext` is registered this way:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<TDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().As<IDbContext>().IfNotRegistered(typeof(TDbContext));
```

We set the `InstancePerLifetimeScope` when registering the `DbContext`, resulting the `DbContext` to be disposed when the api request is finished and throwing `ObjectDisposedException` when we try to use it in the consumer.

Just as an experiment I tried registering the `DbContext` as `SingleInstance` this way:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<TDbContext>().AsSelf().SingleInstance().As<IDbContext>().IfNotRegistered(typeof(TDbContext));
```

But it still throws the ObjectDisposedException when we try using it in the Consumer.

Any ideas why this is happening and how we can solve this?

**EDIT:**

The DbContext is registered via an extension method and passed in as a generic:

```
public static class ContainerBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static void RegisterDbContext<TDbContext>(this ContainerBuilder builder) 
    {
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<TDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().As<IDbContext>().IfNotRegistered(typeof(TDbContext));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is TDbContext coming from exactly? Would you mind posting that part as well. Trying to reproduce the issue at hand.

Comment: The DbContext is registered via an extension method. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are calling this

`containerBuilder.RegisterType<TDbContext>().AsSelf().SingleInstance().As<IDbContext>().IfNotRegistered(typeof(TDbContext));`

after this

`containerBuilder.RegisterType<TDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().As<IDbContext>().IfNotRegistered(typeof(TDbContext));`

the second registration will not have any effect.

Secondly, registering the `DbContext` as a singleton is not a very good idea. It's not thread-safe.

Instead, you can inject `IServiceProvider` in the class where the consumer for the servicebus is registered and resolve the context manually when a new message is being consumed.

Option 1: Using `IServiceProvider`

```cs
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
   using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContext>())
   {
      // do work here
   }
}
```

Option 2: Using `IServiceProvider` and casting down to `ILifetimeScope` using the extension available since `Autofac.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` version 5.

```cs
using (var lifetimeScope = _serviceProvider.GetAutofacRoot().BeginLifetimeScope())
{
   using (var context = lifetimeScope.Resolve<IDbContext>())
   {
      // do work here
   }
}
```

This will create an instance of `IDbContext` everytime you need it and disposes it. While this might take a little longer, it shouldn't be a problem, when messages are consumed in the background.

**EDIT**: You can also register the `DbContext` as `Transient`

```cs
containerBuilder.RegisterType<TDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerDependency().As<IDbContext>().IfNotRegistered(typeof(TDbContext));
```

Comment: Forget to mentioned that we´re not registering the dbContext twice. Just replaced the code. I´ll look into your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that might be a bug in `Autofac`. I will try to get a sample ready and report it, if so.

Comment: It seems to work when creating a new scope. I´ll accept your answer. Thanks!