# Start a new LifetimeScope when a Masstransit consumer is triggered

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, autofac, masstransit

We have the following code to configure the recieveEndpoint:

```
private Action<IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator> GetReceiveEndpointConfigurator(IEnumerable<Type> consumerTypes)
{
    return c =>
        {
            c.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;
            c.SubscribeMessageTopics = false;
            c.MaxDeliveryCount = 3;
            c.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;
            c.UseRetry(Retry.Exponential(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
            foreach (var consumerType in consumerTypes)
            {
                c.Consumer(consumerType, p => _componentContext.Resolve(p));
            }
       };
}
```

All of our consumers are autodiscovered through reflection once our application starts up. We have a `DbContext` that we want to use in many of our consumers. The problem we face is that the DbContext is disposed due to it being registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. More details here:

[AspNet Core Autofac disposing my DbContext even if its registered as SingleInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601854/aspnet-core-autofac-disposing-my-dbcontext-even-if-its-registered-as-singleinsta)

Two suggestions came from this post:

1. Register the `DbContext` as `InstancePerDependency`
2. Create a new Scope within the consumer to start a new `LifetimeScope`

The first suggestion wont work in our application as we have a UnitOfWork which triggers the `SaveChangesAsync` on the `DbContext`. The result would be that the `Repository` and the `UnitOfWork` will get two different instances of the `DbContext` and `SaveChangesAsync` will not persist our changes as the `ChangeTracker` has no changes in the `UnitOfWork` implementation, but these changes belongs to the instance in the `Repository`.

The second suggestion works perfectly. Within my `Consumer` I create a new `LifetimeScope` and resolves the components that I need:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RetailerCreatedEvent> context)
 {
     using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
     {
         var unitOfWork = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>>();
     }
 }
```

It works, but it doesn't look that good.

Is there a way to start a new `LifetimeScope` before the `Consumer` triggers? Or should I rewrite my UnitOfWork-pattern to ensure that the same DbContext is being reused in the `Repositories` and the `UnitOfWork`?

Suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve -- you want an ASP.NET controller and a MassTransit consumer to share a particular DbContext? How do you plan to ensure the same DbContext is given to both?

Comment: Good point, @nizmow. I want the DbContext to be a new instance in the controller, and another instance in the consumer. This doesnt work now, as its registered as InstancePerLifetimeScope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `MassTransit.Autofac` package to resolve your consumers, which will use the AutofacScopeProvider (part of the package) to create a lifetime scope and resolve your consumer.

The [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/autofac.html) shows the configuration, including how to automatically discover your consumers via scanning and add them to MassTransit.

Your consumers shouldn't have any container code in them using this package, they should just add DbContext as a constructor dependency and let Autofac do the work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and a super awesome framework, Chris!